# How to generate new log files with every new run

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I have the following appender in my logback configuration file:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>classname</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${classname}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>target/logs/${classname}.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>[%thread] %level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

How can I configure logback to do the following:

1. On startup always generate a new files and delete existing
2. Clear the file when it is over than 50 mb

Thank you

Comment: maybe try looking into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444520/is-it-possible-to-configure-log4j-to-create-a-new-file-with-every-run-of-the-app

Comment: Please Check this link. This will give the solution for "On startup always generate a new files and delete existing" http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269999/how-do-i-make-log4j-clear-a-log-at-startup Solution for "Clear the file when it is over than 50 mb" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523235/using-log4j-for-clearing-a-file