# log4j, clear logs while they are in use (not just at startup)

Tags: java, log4j

How to clear log4j log files while they are in use (not just at startup)? My first idea would be

- get an existing FileAppender FA
- get all properties of FA
- remove FA from the root logger
- delete the file that FA logged into
- create a new file appender FA2 with the same properties of FA
- add FA2 to the root logger

[How do I make log4j clear a log at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269999/how-do-i-make-log4j-clear-a-log-at-startup) suggests to force a roll-over

Is there a better way?

Some details: I'm improving a tool that can be seen as two applications: An "inner" application logging with log4j and an "outer" one displaying this log via a gui.  The inner and outer applications share their jvm.  The inner one can be started via the gui several times. I now want to clear the log such that it shows only the output of the last run.

I am resticted to small changes only, so letting the inner application run in its own jvm is not an option. Neither is the frequent restart of the whole tool.

Comment: Check these questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269999/how-do-i-make-log4j-clear-a-log-at-startup
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523235/using-log4j-for-clearing-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Try using MaxBackupIndex, see below:

```
log4j.appender.myproject=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myproject.File=/export/logs/myproject.log
log4j.appender.myproject.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.myproject.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.myproject.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

When the file size reachs 10MB the log will start over again.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the rolling file appended in log4j...

It destroys the log file for every run.

Thanks and regards,
Hari